# How to solve Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: package, program-entry-point, java.lang.class

```
folder
|-com
|-  horstmann
|-    corejava
|-        Employee.java
|-        Employee.class
|-    PackageTest
|-      PackageTest.java
|-      PackageTest.class
```

There is my program's structure. Two files, one small class(Employee) and PackageTest which is basically just main function to test class Employee.
In PackageTest.java there is line:

```
import com.horstmann.corejava.*;
```

And  in Employee.java there is line:

```
package com.horstmann.corejava;
```

In terminal I'm sitting in folder and trying to test the program after successfully compiling it with:

```
javac com/PackageTest/PackageTest.java
```

Sadly after :

```
java com.PackageTest.PackageTest
```

I get error from the title.
I'm not sure if it's necessary to post PackageTest.java and Employee.java there. They're really basic classes just to learn how to make package and import them .

Comment: I don't know if it's your typesetting for the question or not, but it looks like PackageTest should be under horstmann: com.horstmann.PackageTest.PackageTest.  Try it.

Comment: It was typoo ,thank you , i edited my post,(it's com.PackagaTest.PackageTest)

Comment: This is an easy problem to solve: Believe the JVM.  If it tells you the .class file is not in the package you specify, change either the location or the import until it's satisfied.  Don't assume that "I did it correctly."   Books make mistakes, too.

Comment: I messed up soooo hard ... PackageTest.java is from 'default package' so i have to put him next to folder 'com' and then just 'javac PackageTest.java' and then 'java PackageTest' ... Sorry for that stupid question.... Anyway ty for your time.

Comment: No worries.  Good luck.